# Hide a <div> if the fiel is empty

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have this  with a field. I want if the fild is empty, don´t show this div.

```
<div class="item noborder">
   <img class="full-image" image-lazy-loader="lines" image-lazy-src="{{restaurantes.fornecedor_visual_foto2}}" />
</div>
```

How I can do it?

I tried:

```
<div ng-hide='{{restaurantes.fornecedor_visual_foto1}} = '' '>
   <div class="item noborder"><img class="full-image" image-lazy-loader="lines" image-lazy-src="{{restaurantes.fornecedor_visual_foto1}}"  /></div>
</div>
```

But it´s wrong...

Comment: won't work since it's an assignation. use `<div ng-hide="restaurantes.fornecedor_visual_foto1 === '' ">`

Comment: You can use `ng-if="expression"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may also come back as undefined or null. You may want to try.

{{restaurantes.fornecedor_visual_foto1}} === '' || {{restaurantes.fornecedor_visual_foto1}} == undefined ||
{{restaurantes.fornecedor_visual_foto1}} == null

However I'd put this in my controller and call a function which would return a bool to keep the html clean